# Issue attempting to query an Excel file... "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.."

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am attempting to query data from within an Excel sheet using my C# application. I seem to be able to connect to the file now but I am getting the following exception...

`The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.`

I'm using a connection string similar to that of [Excel connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

**This is my code...**

The code is basically a method (tucked away in a class) that uses a parameter variable to return a data from one column based on provided data in another....This same method works for SQL connections in my other applications..this is my first swing at an excel sheet however..

```
public static string ReturnDefinition(string remCode)
    {
        string strReturnMessage = "";
        string excelConnectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MEDICARE.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";

        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectString);
        OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$] where Code = @remCode", objConn);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remCode", remCode);

        try
        {
            objConn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader ExcelDataReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (ExcelDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (ExcelDataReader.Read())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ExcelDataReader["Description"]))
                    {
                        strReturnMessage = "** ERROR **";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strReturnMessage = ExcelDataReader["Description"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strReturnMessage = "** ERROR **";
            }
            ExcelDataReader.Close();
            return strReturnMessage;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "** ERROR **: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

**5/30**

I realize there is literature out there that covers connections to Excel using OLEDB but I think I've boiled the issue down to a read issue in the sheet its self. Again, this is the first time I've tried to connect to Excel. My HDR is set to true, as I intend to treat the sheet like a SQL table.

**Changed Excel to v.14.0 in Extended Properties**

I may have been targeting the wrong version of excel. Specifically, the excel sheet was created using Office 2010. Using [This Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) for reference, I changed the version from 12.0 to 14.0.

Now I get `Could not find installable ISAM`

Comment: The dollar symbol in "Sheet1$" is rather odd.  Are you sure that this is the actual name of the spreadsheet in the workbook?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter. I've tried with and without, both attempts producing the same error. Most articles I have read include the dollar after Sheet1 so I figured it was a necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I've got it figured out for now.
At least I can get to the sheet anyway.

I'll just need to sort out whats going on with my data types. 
I now get `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

The data being passed from my parameter variable is a string but the column name ("Code") I am trying to reach contains strings in some rows and int32 in others. If it were SQL I would say this column would be of type CHAR(whatever). I don't know in this case.

Anyway, here is my own resolution...it seems all I needed to do was assign the sheet name to a variable and then include that variable in my query.

```
enter public static string ReturnDefinition(string remCode)
    {
        string strReturnMessage = "";
        string excelConnectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MEDICARE.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";
        string excelSheet = "Sheet1$";

        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectString);
        OleDbCommand excelCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from ["+ excelSheet + "] where Code = @remCode", objConn);
        excelCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remCode", remCode);

        try
        {
            objConn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader ExcelDataReader = excelCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (ExcelDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (ExcelDataReader.Read())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ExcelDataReader["Description"]))
                    {
                        strReturnMessage = "** ERROR **";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strReturnMessage = ExcelDataReader["Description"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strReturnMessage = "** ERROR **";
            }
            ExcelDataReader.Close();
            return strReturnMessage;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "** ERROR **: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```